# ViewController's private data set to nil after returning from segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I have two views. The main view is ViewController and the next is AddItemViewController. ViewController has a tableview that lists items that you add when you go to AddItemViewController. There is a button on AddItemViewController that segues back to ViewController. The problem is, upon returning to ViewController expecting that an item be added, the private data of ViewController is suddenly set to nil. I have lost data and any chance to interact with my objects after returning from the segue.

Here is the data that's getting set to nil

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) costEstimator *myCost;
@property NSString *testString;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my prepareforsegue code in the AddItemViewController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
ViewController *vC = [segue destinationViewController];
[vC addSomething:_selectedItem withQuantity:[_quantBox.text doubleValue]];
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Segues (other than unwinds) always instantiate new controllers! So, if you're not using an unwind, you're not "going back", you're creating a new instance of ViewController,

Comment: Thank you! So what is common practice in most applications? Do people never use segues? Why aren't unwinds taught in the first few chapters of iOS basic tutorials like segues are?

Comment: I have no idea why people who write tutorials write what they do.  An unwind is a segue, it's just a different kind, so you can use that, or go back in code by popping (if you pushed) or dismissing (if you've presented). Before you do any iOS programming, you should read Apple's documentation. I would start with the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS". It explains a lot of important concepts.

Comment: @rdelmar -- is that true in a navigation stack context? When you push a new ViewController, the original one is still on the stack and owned by the parent navigationController -- it's not released on push.

Comment: @AnnaDickinson, I'm not sure what you're asking. Yes, the original one is still on the stack, but that doesn't have anything to do with the fact that a non-unwind segue will create a new instance of that initial controller (so the navigation stack will have 3 controllers on it after the segue to "go back").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pop the AddItemViewController in this case. When you segued from ViewController to AddItemViewController, I am guessing you did a push. What this does effectively is it adds AddItemViewController ontop of ViewController in the memory stack. By 'segue-ing' again from AddItemViewController to ViewController, you are adding ANOTHER ViewController instance ONTOP of AddItemViewController. This is why you think you are losing your data when in actuality, you aren't. You are only seeing the wrong view controller.